# getting error Subscribe is not a function in jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am getting error, subscribe is not a function in angular unit testing

this is the call that I am using in component

```
this.myService.employees.subscribe(emp => this.emp = emp);
```

when I create a mock service for this to test the above code getting error.

Can anyone suggest how can I test the above observable.

I want to send mock data when `this.myService.employees.subscribe(emp => this.emp = emp);` subscribe from component

**employees** is **BehaviorSubject** observable

Comment: What does your mock service look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you share code how you configure the service in the test?

Usually you should do something like that: https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/extra/mock-observables

The best option is to use a testing library such as [ng-mocks](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks)

```js
beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(MyComponent, MyService));

it('test', () => {
  const employees$ = new Subject();
  MockInstance(MyService, 'employees', employees$);

  const fixture = MockRender(MyComponent);
  employees$.next([]);
  // some assertions.
});
```